# Are there any other ways to access the parent frame?

Tags: javascript, html, frames

I'm trying to block out a javascript that's within an iframe from possibly gaining access to the parent document.  While I realize there's no 100% sure way to prevent this from happening(), I need to take all steps I can think of.  So far I've only come up with these 2.... can you think of any?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var top = null,
        parent = null;
</script>
```

Comment: If you control what's in the iframe (which you must if you're adding the above code to it) why are you even worried about it gaining access to the parent document?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, why not put the parent document onto a different domain than the iframed one?

That way, the protection becomes watertight - the  browser will enforce the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for you.